# New pointer in class method must be casted into a reference

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have two classes, let's call them A and B

```
class A:
{
  public:
    //Some functions

    A *getNewA() const;

  private:
    //some attributes
}

class B:
{
  public:
    //Some functions
  private:
    A &reftoA;
}
```

In the main code, I ***must*** generate a new A thanks to the A::getNewA() method. And this **must** go to B::reftoA, as written in class B.

Here is the A::getNewA() method :

```
A *A::getNewA()
{
    A *newA = new A;
    return newA;
}
```

OK. So now I call getNewA and want to store the results in reftoA, which is a *reference* to A. In a B function (which take a reference to A as parameter)

```
B::foo(A &paramA)
{
    reftoA = *(paramA.getNewA());
}
```

I thought this should have been working, but it won't.
Because when dereferencing, reftoA will always take the this object and not the new allocated object.

Let's be clearer and let's modify the functions to output the results

```
A * A::getNewA()
{
    A *newA = new A;
    std::cout << "New pointer " << newA << std::endl;
    std::cout << "this pointer" << this << std::endl;

    return A;
}

void B::foo(A &paramA)
{

    reftoA = *(paramA.getNewA());
    std::cout << "new generated pointer " << &reftoA << std::endl;
}
```

Here is one of the output :

```
New pointer : 004FFAEC
this pointer: 0069D888
New generated pointer : 0069D888 //Expected : 004FFAEC
```

I can't get this "new generated pointer" to be the same than the new pointer the A::getNewA() returns after having allocated the memory. Of course, I guess there is some point with dereferencing the pointer to store it in a reference.
I know reference are used with existing object. Maybe the new object A::getNewA() should allocate memory for won't work as I expected.

I could use pointer instead reference in B::foo(), I know, but ***I can't***

I think I am misunderstanding something about refrence and pointer, but I don't know what.

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Wait, what? `return A`? How does that build? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us?

Comment: Also, you have a memory leak. You discard the pointer returned by `getNewA` (well, assuming you actually return `newA`) so you really have nothing to `delete`.

Comment: Lastly, and the probable source of your problem: *You can't reassign a reference*. What you're doing is assigning *to* the *object*. You're effectively doing `reftoA.operator=(*(paramA.getNewA()))`

Comment: OK... So, coudn't I use reference to pointer ? As I need to delete the newA (and you where right about the possible memory leak). Maybe I should have a variable like A&* reftoA, which implies me to change the B class structure

Comment: *Why* do you need `reftoA` to be a reference? That's the major problem here. Can't it be a (smart) pointer?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you can not reassign a reference. You can change only the value of the referenced object.

So you have to initialize the reference in the initializer list of the constructor of the class B.

Take into account that there is a typo in your code snippet

```
A*A::getNewA()
{
A *newA = new A;
std::cout << "New pointer " << newA << std::endl;
std::cout << "this pointer" << this << std::endl;

return A;
^^^^^^^^^ 
}
```

I think you mean

```
A*A::getNewA() const
               ^^^^^
{
A *newA = new A;
std::cout << "New pointer " << newA << std::endl;
std::cout << "this pointer" << this << std::endl;

return newA;
^^^^^^^^^^^ 
}
```

Always try to provide a verifiable complete example.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public :
    //Some functions

    A* getNewA() const
    {
        A *newA = new A;
        std::cout << "New pointer " << newA << std::endl;
        std::cout << "this pointer" << this << std::endl;

    return newA;
    }

private :
    //some attributes
};

class B
{
public :
    B( const A& a ) : reftoA( *a.getNewA() )
    {
        std::cout << "&reftoA " << &reftoA << std::endl;
    }
private :
    A& reftoA;
};

int main() 
{
    A a;

    B b( a );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
New pointer 0x2b392afbec20
this pointer0x7ffd287ad0af
&reftoA 0x2b392afbec20
```

As you can see the values of the `New pointer` and `&reftoA` are equal each other.

To make it more clear consider a very simple example

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int x = 10;
    int y = 20;

    int &r = x;

    r = y;

    std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "y = " << y << std::endl;
    std::cout << "r = " << r << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "&x = " << &x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "&y = " << &y << std::endl;
    std::cout << "&r = " << &r << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
x = 20
y = 20
r = 20

&x = 0x7ffd88ad47a8
&y = 0x7ffd88ad47ac
&r = 0x7ffd88ad47a8
```

This statement

```
    r = y;
```

did not force the reference to refer the object `y`. It just reassigned the value of the referenced object `x`.

References have to be initialized when they are created.

Comment: Thanks you ! After having understood references couldn't be reassigned (which seems now logic to me) I had thought to write something like yours. But you did it better, I do understand better now. Thanks you for your answer, it's useful to me to understand how references work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are misunderstanding something.

`getNewA()` is returning a pointer.  it's not a smart pointer, you want to look into those and that's all I'll say on the matter.

on returning a pointer, you must keep a reference to this pointer else you will be unable to delete it and you'll get a memory leak.  Thus you MUST have somewhere  `A* a = A::getNewA()` and then later, when you no longer need it  `delete a`;

Where you need to pass a reference to A, you can do `foo(*a)` which will dereference the pointer and pass a reference to the object it's pointing to.

But in summary, for all new code, smart pointers; there's no excuse to not use them.

Side note:  Your code example had a few other issues; such as getNewA wasn't static; I'm going to take the code as a working example of your understanding, and not a working example.

Edit:  On re-reading your example, the getNewA is intentionally non-static.  I think this question is actually an XY problem  (ie you're asking a question you've forced yourself into but isn't your actual problem); but I hope this addresses your misunderstanding of pointers and references.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning the pointer in the `getNewA`-Method

```
A* A::getNewA()
{
    A *newA = new A;
    return A; // you are returning A and not newA
}
```

And if you want to reassign the reference to a you can use a [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper)

```
class B :
{
public :
void foo(A& paramA) {
    reftoA = *(paramA.getNewA());
}

private :
std::reference_wrapper<A> reftoA;
}
```